# Mercurial merge branches? (abort: push creates new remote branches)

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to Mercurial, and I made the mistake of making different changes on different systems before the main repository was up to date.  (I understand this is what Mercurial is built for, but my thick brain is struggling to resolve the issue.)

Now on my primary development server, everything is up to date and committed.  However...

```
$ hg push
abort: push creates new remote branches: 4f2672f039d7!
(use 'hg push --new-branch' to create new remote branches)
```

I don't really want a new branch.  I just want all the changes to be merged.

```
$ hg heads
changeset:   459:ff5f94e44aba
branch:      4f2672f039d7
tag:         tip
parent:      458:e63d02baf4cf
parent:      455:267abda62069
user:        mike@...
date:        Tue Sep 13 14:25:16 2011 -0400
summary:     Images from prof

changeset:   455:267abda62069
parent:      453:a74757e26357
user:        mike@localhost.localdomain
date:        Tue Sep 13 09:08:12 2011 -0400
summary:     images for FLC
```

Point me in the right direction?

EDIT: (adding detail)

When I try to merge, I get the following result:

```
$ hg merge
abort: branch '4f2672f039d7' has one head - please merge with an explicit rev
(run 'hg heads' to see all heads)
```

I have tried `hg merge ff5f94e44aba`, and all of the revs listed above, and each one returns the same result:

```
$ hg merge 267abda62069
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've accidentally created a branch with a silly name.  What you most likely want to do is reapply your changes with a branch name that makes better sense.  There's no totally automatic way of doing this, but you can extract each changeset as a patch, revert to the point where you messed up and reapply those changes on the proper branch.

Basically what you need to do is look at the changelog; probably by running `hg out` to see what's missing from the central repository.  Make a note of each of the revs that you want to keep.

Next update to the last good revision.  Make sure that you are on the branch you wanted your commits to be on.

Now you will apply each of the changes you made and commit each one.  You can automate this process something like this:

```
BADREVS="123 124 125 126"

recommit() { hg di -c $1 | patch -p1;  hg ci -m "$(hg log -r $1 --template '{desc}')";}
for rev in $BADREVS; do
    recommit $rev
done
```

Now you've got your changes in your local repository twice; once as the commits on the weird branch and again on the right branch.  You can push those changes to the central repo using `hg push -b GOODBRANCH` so that only the changes to the right branch go up;  Alternatively, you can install the [strip extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip) to remove the changes you didn't want from the local repo and then you can push as normal.

By the sound of it; you will still have to deal with the changes made to the central repository before you can push, since you pushed changes from another repo.  You probably want to do this merging *after* you clean up the change history in the local repo.

Comment: I basically did this, but I used `hg strip` (mq extension) to just remove the changesets, then re-added the necessary changes that I had saved from `hg diff`.

Comment: I tend to do the strip afterwards so that I can see all of the changes, good and bad.  I didn't emphasize the use of strip because it's an extension and history rewriting isn't held in high regard in the mercurial community, even though it is very practical.

Answer (score 4):

Pull from remote and then update / merge / commit first. Then you won't make new branches.

Comment: That's what I should have done.  But I didn't.  (I guess I like to learn the hard way.)  So now I need to figure out how to fix the fact that I did it wrong.

Comment: You should still be able to do it. Right now, you have 2 heads. That isn't a problem... the `$hg merge` command is for this exact thing. This is a 100% normal part of the workflow, and Mercurial supports it really, really well.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I am having problems with that and will update the question to reflect it.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this happen when I missed a merge. I like the TortoiseHg workbench for this because it can be a little easier to find what you missed through visualization.

A good way to avoid this in the future, how I stopped getting this error, is the fetch extension. Set your post pull to fetch and it will automatically merge for you, which is very nice. If there's a conflict it brings up whatever conflict resolver you use.

Comment: It looks like the OP is on a non-windows platform, but I agree that TortoiseHg is great for Windows users.

Comment: I miss non-windows so much. But I guess I get to use fun tools like TortoiseHg this way.

Comment: I agree. Non-windows is better overall, but the suckiness of windows means that lots of people have built really nice GUI applications to get around the pain-points. Now if only they would just all port over nicely ;)