# How to undo "abort: push creates new remote heads on branch" in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am aware of [Mercurial for Beginners: The Definitive Practical Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/) and answers like [Mercurial merge branches? (abort: push creates new remote branches)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448405/mercurial-merge-branches-abort-push-creates-new-remote-branches)

Here I've inadvertently created a situation where Mercurial wants to create a new remote head.  What's the best way to undo this, and leave little or no trace of this mistake on the remote side?

```
###> hg push
pushing to http://example.com
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote heads on branch 'default'!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)

###> hg revert --all -r tip

###> hg update -C
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

###> hg incoming
comparing with http://example.com
searching for changes
no changes found

###> hg summary
parent: 488:e3db024fe901 tip
 Misc.
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: 6 new changesets, 2 branch heads (merge)

###> hg pull
pulling from http://example.com
searching for changes
no changes found

###> hg glog
@  changeset:   488:e3db024fe901
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     Misc.
|
o  changeset:   487:b207579b9d41
|  parent:      480:ce775708800c
|  summary:     Misc.
|
| o  changeset:   486:59a7a5b34c7f
| |  user:        other
| |  summary:     fixes
| |
| o  changeset:   485:b28264333e18
| |  user:        other
| |  summary:     binary
```

If I merge, it sort of seems OK:

```
hg merge
abort: outstanding uncommitted merges
```

But `hg diff` shows all sorts of changes I did not make.  I'm willing to re-apply my changes... how can I bring this all back to a single tip, abandoning all local changes?

Comment: what does hg outgoing output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like when you've done an `hg merge`, you haven't committed the resulting changeset.

When you merge in another branch (in your case you may need to specify `hg merge 486` to merge in the other users changes), it merges that branch into your working directory.  You then need to check that all conflicts are resolved (if there are any) by using a merge tool, or manually editing the files (and then running `hg resolve` on any conflicts).  Once this is done you need to `hg commit` your new, merged changeset.

This would explain why `hg diff` gives you lots of changes you didn't make -- they're changes made on the other branch, that you have yet to commit. If you run `hg summary` or `hg parents` in your working directory, you should see two parents listed: `486` and `488`.  You should `hg commit` this working directory, creating a new merged `489`.

If you want to undo the current merge and start again, you're correct in trying to run `hg update -C`, which will set your working directory back to its original (unmerged) state.

If you want to *get rid of* your changes (`487` and `488` - you state you don't mind re-applying your changes), the easiest option without resorting to extensions is simply to re-clone the repository and continue your work from there.

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of changes (ex 487 and 488):
If you feel (as I do) that re-cloning the repository, as recommended above and even [officially recommended here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches#Using_clone) is ridiculous, then you should get [MqExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration)

Once Mq is enabled, you can easily remove changes you don't want:

```
hg strip 487
hg strip 488
```

Comment: The officially recommended link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

I did not do merge, but suddenly I am viewing the message the op has posted. When I do a **hg pull**, in the command line it shows **abort !repository default not found**.